# How to create a uniform grid of n-dimensional vectors using numpy (in other words, uniformly fill a n-dimensional hypercube)?

Tags: python, numpy

In one dimension a "grid" would be an array of numbers between let's say 0 and 100.
In two dimensions the grid would be an array of points like [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2]... [1,0], [1, 1] ... [99, 99]. In three dimensions and more dimensions it would look similar.

My current output is like that:

[image: wrong output]

It doesn't create every combination of values for each value in the nth - 1 column.

The code I use is:

```py
import numpy as np

class Cube:
    side_len = 100
    def __init__(self, n):
        current_point = np.zeros(n)
        self.arr = []
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(Cube.side_len):
                self.arr.append(current_point.copy())
                current_point[i] += 1.0
        self.arr.append([Cube.side_len for _ in range(n)])
        self.arr = np.array(self.arr)
        np.random.shuffle(self.arr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cube(10)
```

I tried also with [meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) but I could not understand the documentation. I wanted it to be a shallow list of points but I get X, Y and I don't get what I am supposed to do with that?

Comment: `np.indices((100,100,100)).reshape(3,-1).T`? IIUC

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny it actually does what I wanted to do. (But it turns out it's too memory heavy lol.)

Comment: Change the `dtype` to `np.uint8`? `np.indices((100,100,100), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(3,-1).T`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I've tried that but it's still not enough for 10 dimensions and a side_len of 10. I think I misunderstand the problem and have asked the wrong question, but I believe your answer to it is correct. I still haven't understood Tim's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way you do it.  Meshgrid with 3 dimensions returns a list of three things, which are the values for the 3 axes to get a uniform spread of points.  You can then use `vstack` to stack those together, and transpose to get a list of 3D coordinates:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.linspace(0,100,101)
>>> x = np.meshgrid( a, a, a )
>>> y = np.vstack(list(map(np.ravel,x))).T
>>> y
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.],
       [  0.,   0.,   2.],
       ...,
       [100., 100.,  98.],
       [100., 100.,  99.],
       [100., 100., 100.]])
>>>
```

Credit to this post:
[How to convert the output of meshgrid to the corresponding array of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864445/how-to-convert-the-output-of-meshgrid-to-the-corresponding-array-of-points)

Remember that the grid is the size of one axis cubed, so these very quickly get large.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I have run this code and it doesn't look like it outputs the right thing. After I changed `a = np.arange(0,100,101)` to `a = np.arange(0,100,1)` (because otherwise it was just [0]) I got a single column of 3 times repeated values of 0..99.

Comment: Oops, I actually used `linspace`, not `arange`, and I used too many parens in the `meshgrid` call.  Fixed now.  Your `arange` should also work.  It will produce integers instead of floats.