# How to create a multi-dimensional grid in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have seen similar questions but none that need the format of the output array of shape `(numpoints, dim)`

Here is a simple example of what I have for `dim=2`

```py
import numpy as np

bounds = [0.5, 0.5]
n = [10,10]
dim = 2
x = np.linspace(-bounds[0], bounds[0], n[0])
y = np.linspace(-bounds[1], bounds[1], n[1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

s = X.shape
data = np.zeros((n[0]*n[1],dim)) 

# convert mesh into point vector for which the model can be evaluated
c = 0
for i in range(s[0]):
    for j in range(s[1]):
        data[c,0] = X[i,j]
        data[c,1] = Y[i,j]
        c = c+1;
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1])
```

[image]

Is there a faster/better way of doing this so that the data are arranged in this way? I want a general method that could work for any `dim`.

**Edit**: Suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12891609/17986681) does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert the output of meshgrid to the corresponding array of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864445/how-to-convert-the-output-of-meshgrid-to-the-corresponding-array-of-points)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny when I use the suggested 'meshgrid2' function I get the error 'map' object not subscriptable. So yes, the question is similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with this function that is general enough for any `dim`:

```py
def get_grid_of_points(n, *args):
    ls = [np.linspace(-i,i,n) for i in args]
    mesh_ls = np.meshgrid(*ls)
    all_mesh = [np.reshape(x, [-1]) for x in mesh_ls]
    grid_points = np.stack(all_mesh, axis=1)
    return grid_points
```

`get_grid_of_points(10, 0.5, 0.5)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that can be vectorized with

```
axis_coords = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')
data = np.hstack([c.reshape(-1, 1) for c in axis_coords])
```

`c.reshape(-1, 1)` just reshapes `c` from (`HxW` to `(H*W)x1`) so that it can be stacked horizontally.

Note - if you're looking to generalize to more dims you probably want to switch to `indexing='ij'` so it's arranged by (row, column, dim2, dim3, ...) rather than (column, row, dim2, dim3, ...) since in numpy rows are considered the 0'th dimension and columns the 1st.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this is not general enough for any dimension. I posted my answer, take a look at it and let me know.

Comment: Looks good to me - just watch out for the `indexing='ij'` vs `indexing='xy'` thing when generalising to higher dims.