# change font size of facet titles using seaborn facetgrid heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Note: this is a different question than "[How can I change the font size using seaborn FacetGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328003/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-using-seaborn-facetgrid)".  The methods suggested there do not work when using a heatmap inside a facetgrid.

How can I change the font size of the facet titles when plotting heatmaps inside a facetgrid?

The code below tries two methods, passing `fontsize=` to `set_titles()` and wrapping the whole thing in a plotting context.  As far as I can tell, neither seems to have any effect on facet titles when using heatmap, although the fontweight did change.  Are there any other options for controlling facet title when using heatmap?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns

print("seaborn version {}".format(sns.__version__))
# R expand.grid() function in Python
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131385/1135316
def expandgrid(*itrs):
   product = list(itertools.product(*itrs))
   return {'Var{}'.format(i+1):[x[i] for x in product] for i in range(len(itrs))}

methods=['method 1', 'method2', 'method 3', 'method 4']
times = range(0,100,10)
data = pd.DataFrame(expandgrid(methods, times, times))
data.columns = ['method', 'dtsi','rtsi']
data['nw_score'] = np.random.sample(data.shape[0])

def facet(data,color):
    data = data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score')
    g = sns.heatmap(data, cmap='Blues', cbar=False)

with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="method", col_wrap=2, size=3, aspect=1)
    g = g.map_dataframe(facet)
    g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", fontweight='bold', fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want to pass `size=` to `set_titles`, not `fontsize=`

Answer (score 14):

Thanks @mwaskon, that is the answer - use `size=` when called `set_titles`.

That leads to more questions, like

- Can you please change `set_titles` used `fontweight=` and `fontsize=` instead of
  `fontweight=` and `size=`?  `size=` is use elsewhere for the facet height in inches.
- why is `sns.plotting_context` completely ineffective in this
  context?

Comment: `set_titles` is just passing additional keyword arguments through to the matplotlib method `ax.set_title`, and that takes `size`, so there isn't anything seaborn can do about that. As for `plotting_context`, because of the way it works, `font_scale` is ignored if `context` is `None`, so you want `plotting_context("notebook", font_scale=5.5)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks again, I grabbed the `plotting_context()` suggestion from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27714134/1135316).  I'll post a comment there pointing to your answer - might save some grief.