# Getting a legend in a seaborn FacetGrid heatmap plot

Tags: python, numpy, plot, heatmap, seaborn

How can we get legends for seaborn `FacetGrid` heatmaps? The `.add_legend()` method isn't working for me.

Using code from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31864770/1461210):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns

print("seaborn version {}".format(sns.__version__))
# R expand.grid() function in Python
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131385/1135316
def expandgrid(*itrs):
   product = list(itertools.product(*itrs))
   return {'Var{}'.format(i+1):[x[i] for x in product] for i in range(len(itrs))}

methods=['method 1', 'method2', 'method 3', 'method 4']
times = range(0,100,10)
data = pd.DataFrame(expandgrid(methods, times, times))
data.columns = ['method', 'dtsi','rtsi']
data['nw_score'] = np.random.sample(data.shape[0])

def facet(data,color):
    data = data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score')
    g = sns.heatmap(data, cmap='Blues', cbar=False)

with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="method", col_wrap=2, size=3, aspect=1)
    g = g.map_dataframe(facet)
    g.add_legend()
    g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", fontweight='bold', fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what sort of legend/legends you want? Legends are useful when you have multiple artists within a single set of axes. In your example there is only a single artist (heatmap) per subplot, and each subplot is uniquely titled with the corresponding column name, so it seems to me that a legend would be redundant in this case.

Comment: You'll want to adapt the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356359/one-colorbar-for-seaborn-heatmaps-in-subplot)

Comment: Thanks @mwaskom!  I'm new to this and stoked to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want (in matplotlib lingo) is a colorbar, not a legend. In matplotlib, the former is used for continuous data, while the latter is used for categorical data. Colorbar support isn't built into `FacetGrid`, but it is not hard to expand your example code to add a colorbar:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns

methods=['method 1', 'method2', 'method 3', 'method 4']
times = range(0, 100, 10)
data = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(methods, times, times)))
data.columns = ['method', 'dtsi','rtsi']
data['nw_score'] = np.random.sample(data.shape[0])

def facet_heatmap(data, color, **kws):
    data = data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score')
    sns.heatmap(data, cmap='Blues', **kws)  # <-- Pass kwargs to heatmap

with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="method", col_wrap=2, size=3, aspect=1)

cbar_ax = g.fig.add_axes([.92, .3, .02, .4])  # <-- Create a colorbar axes

g = g.map_dataframe(facet_heatmap,
                    cbar_ax=cbar_ax,
                    vmin=0, vmax=1)  # <-- Specify the colorbar axes and limits

g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", fontweight='bold', fontsize=18)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(right=.9)  # <-- Add space so the colorbar doesn't overlap the plot
```

[image]

I've indicated the changes I made and the rationale for them as inline comments.