# seaborn.lmplot with single axes labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, axis-labels, facet

What I need should be straighforward but I couldn't find a solution. Say we draw the following seaborn.lmplot:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", col="day", hue="day",
               data=tips, col_wrap=2, height=3)
```

[image: tips]

I simply want to have a **single** label for the x-axis and a **single** label for the y-axis instead of two as currently.

In other words, that the word 'tip' be printed only one time on the centre left of the graph, and that the word 'total_bill' be printed only one time on the bottom centre of the graph.

How do we do this?

EDIT: there is a similar question here [One shared x-axis label for Seaborn FacetGrid subplots (layouts/spacing?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460622/one-shared-x-axis-label-for-seaborn-facetgrid-subplots-layouts-spacing) yet it is not elaborated and does not solve my issue.

Comment: thanks @BigBen I had seen that answer but it is not very elaborated and I have several issues with it: I can add text, but the original labels stay where they are (so they overalp with my new labels), and also I cannot work out how to change the position of the added text. I think other users might want to know how to do this in detail, perhaps?

Comment: @BigBen I edited my question and now cite the one you mentioned

Comment: [`Axes.set_xlabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html). Set one axis label as a blank string `''`, and [Figure labels: suptitle, supxlabel, supylabel](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html)

Comment: Since this has been closed, something like `g.set_axis_labels('', '')`, `g.fig.supxlabel('total_bill')`
`g.fig.supylabel('tips')`

Comment: @BigBen thanks so much, this worked like a charm. And your comment should be accepted as answer since the referenced answer is quite less developped than yours!

Comment: Actually it's even easier with `supxlabel` and `supylabel` (edited my comment).

Comment: apologies, this one actually is quite helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots. Many thanks again in any case