# how to repeat a row n number of times in a csv file using python

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to work on merging multipe files in a desired layout.
One of my problems involve repeating each row of the csv file (excluding header) n number of times. e.g

Initial file:

```
header1 header2 header3
abc       123    a1
def       456    b1
ghi       789    c1
```

After modification, the file should look like (e.g 3 repetitions):

```
header1 header2 header3
abc       123    a1
abc       123    a1
abc       123    a1
def       456    b1
def       456    b1
def       456    b1
ghi       789    c1
ghi       789    c1
ghi       789    c1
```

What is the best way to do it in python using either csv or pandas.
Apologies if the question is too trivial but I am new to such file manipulations using python and didnt find any similar problem on forum.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't know where to start, trying reading the Python documentation for file I/O: https://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html. And for the csv modle: https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html. Then try breaking the problem down into smaller parts and solving one part at a time

Comment: See here for discussion of similar problem with multiple solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130883/r-expand-grid-function-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Using the `csv` module, you can do it as follows:

```
import csv

with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout, open('in.txt', 'r') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        writer.writerow(next(reader))
        for l in reader:
            for i in range(3):
                writer.writerow(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

for 3 times, you can do:

```
three_df = pd.concat([df,df,df])
```

you can easily write a loop that will do this n times.