# How to speed up seaborn heatmaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

Struggling with an issue of `searborn facetgrid heatmaps` slowness. I have expanded my data set from previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099912/trouble-with-saving-grouped-seaborn-facetgrid-heatmap-data-into-a-directory) and thanks to @Diziet Asahi to provide a solution to facetgrid issue.

Now, I have 20x20 grid with 625 points in each grid to be mapped. It takes forever to get an output for even one layer `little1`. I have a thousands of `little` layers in real data.

My code is along the lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

print("seaborn version {}".format(sns.__version__))
# R expand.grid() function in Python
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131385/1135316
def expandgrid(*itrs):
   product = list(itertools.product(*itrs))
   return {'Var{}'.format(i+1):[x[i] for x in product] for i in range(len(itrs))}

ltt= ['little1']

methods=["m" + str(i) for i in range(1,21)]
labels=["l" + str(i) for i in range(1,20)]

times = range(0,100,4)
data = pd.DataFrame(expandgrid(ltt,methods,labels, times, times))
data.columns = ['ltt','method','labels','dtsi','rtsi']
data['nw_score'] = np.random.choice([0,1],data.shape[0])
```

`data` outputs to:

```
Out[36]: 
            ltt method labels  dtsi  rtsi  nw_score
0       little1     m1     l1     0     0         1
1       little1     m1     l1     0     4         0
2       little1     m1     l1     0     8         0
3       little1     m1     l1     0    12         1
4       little1     m1     l1     0    16         0
        ...    ...    ...   ...   ...       ...
237495  little1    m20    l19    96    80         0
237496  little1    m20    l19    96    84         1
237497  little1    m20    l19    96    88         0
237498  little1    m20    l19    96    92         0
237499  little1    m20    l19    96    96         1

[237500 rows x 6 columns]
```

Plotting and defining `facet` function:

```
labels_fill = {0:'red',1:'blue'}

del methods
del labels

def facet(data,color):
    data = data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score')
    g = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=ListedColormap(['red', 'blue']), cbar=False,annot=True)

for lt in data.ltt.unique():
    with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
        g = sns.FacetGrid(data[data.ltt==lt],row="labels", col="method", size=2, aspect=1,margin_titles=False)
        g = g.map_dataframe(facet)
        g.add_legend()
        g.set_titles(template="")

        for ax,method in zip(g.axes[0,:],data.method.unique()):
            ax.set_title(method, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)
        for ax,label in zip(g.axes[:,0],data.labels.unique()):
            ax.set_ylabel(label, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12, rotation=0, ha='right', va='center')
        g.fig.suptitle(lt, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)
        g.fig.tight_layout()
        g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8) # make some room for the title

        g.savefig(lt+'.png', dpi=300)
```

[image]

I stopped the code after some time and we can see that grids are being filled one-by-one which is time-consuming. Generating this heatmap is unbearably slow.

I wonder is there a better way to speed up the process ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest its same. I just don't understand why it is downvoted.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Apologies to doing that. But I put a lot of effort to put everything together and be more precise about the problem statement. If somebody comes and downvotes without an explanation that is unacceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn is slow. 
If you use matplotlib instead of seaborn, you arrive at half a minute or so per figure. This is still long, but given that you produce a ~12000x12000 pixel figure, it's kind of expected.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("seaborn version {}".format(sns.__version__))
# R expand.grid() function in Python
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131385/1135316
def expandgrid(*itrs):
   product = list(itertools.product(*itrs))
   return {'Var{}'.format(i+1):[x[i] for x in product] for i in range(len(itrs))}

ltt= ['little1']

methods=["m" + str(i) for i in range(1,21)]
#methods=['method 1', 'method 2', 'method 3', 'method 4']
#labels = ['label1','label2']
labels=["l" + str(i) for i in range(1,20)]

times = range(0,100,4)
data = pd.DataFrame(expandgrid(ltt,methods,labels, times, times))
data.columns = ['ltt','method','labels','dtsi','rtsi']
#data['nw_score'] = np.random.sample(data.shape[0])
data['nw_score'] = np.random.choice([0,1],data.shape[0])

labels_fill = {0:'red',1:'blue'}

del methods
del labels


cmap=ListedColormap(['red', 'blue'])

def facet(data, ax):
    data = data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score')
    ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap)

def myfacetgrid(data, row, col, figure=None):
    rows = np.unique(data[row].values)  
    cols = np.unique(data[col].values)

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(rows), len(cols), 
                            figsize=(2*len(cols)+1, 2*len(rows)+1))


    for i, r in enumerate(rows):
        row_data = data[data[row] == r]
        for j, c in enumerate(cols):
            this_data = row_data[row_data[col] == c]
            facet(this_data, axs[i,j])
    return fig, axs


for lt in data.ltt.unique():

    with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
        t = time.time()
        fig, axs = myfacetgrid(data[data.ltt==lt], row="labels", col="method")
        print(time.time()-t)
        for ax,method in zip(axs[0,:],data.method.unique()):
            ax.set_title(method, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)
        for ax,label in zip(axs[:,0],data.labels.unique()):
            ax.set_ylabel(label, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12, rotation=0, ha='right', va='center')
        print(time.time()-t)
        fig.suptitle(lt, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)
        fig.tight_layout()
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8) # make some room for the title
        print(time.time()-t)
        fig.savefig(lt+'.png', dpi=300)
        print(time.time()-t)
```

Here the timing divide into ~6 seconds creating the facetgrid, ~7 seconds optimizing the grid layout (via tight_layout - think about leaving it out!), and 15 seconds drawing the figure.